# Import 3D model in SceneKit - Swift

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit

I'm creating a game where the player can control a cube.

He could buy new cubes.

I created the basic cube like that :

```
// MAIN CUBE

mainCubeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0.0)
mainCubeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
mainCubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: mainCubeGeometry)
mainCubeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(mainCubeNode)
```

I would like to know how use 3D models (dae) of cubes created on any software (SketchUp per exemple). I don't really understand how to load the 3D file when the scene is created (`scene = SCNScene(named: "3d.scnassets/cube.dae")`) because it is a scene, so it import a scene into my original scene, while I just want to import a 3D model in a node to use it like my basic cube.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I found a solution on this post : How do you load a .dae file into an SCNNode in IOS SceneKit?

```
class func collada2SCNNode(filepath:String) -> SCNNode {

    var node = SCNNode()
    let scene = SCNScene(named: filepath)
    var nodeArray = scene!.rootNode.childNodes

    for childNode in nodeArray {

        node.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)

    }

    return node

}
```

Use :

```
let myNode = collada2SCNNode("nodes.scnassets/node.dae")
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(myNode)
```

Answer (score 3):

`SCNScene(named:)` returns an `SCNNode` with all of the objects from that DAE file as child nodes. Load the file, retrieve the bodies you're interested in, and add them to your scene's root node.

Here are a couple of snippets from the [Fox sample app from WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Fox/Introduction/Intro.html). The `Character` class has a `node` property initialized like this:

```
    let characterScene = SCNScene(named: "game.scnassets/panda.scn")!
    let characterTopLevelNode = characterScene.rootNode.childNodes[0]
    node.addChildNode(characterTopLevelNode)
```

And then add the character to the scene like this:

```
    // Add the character to the scene.
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(character.node)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I get the error message `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, do you know why ? All works well with the solution in my post edit

Comment: As a guess, without seeing where in your code you hit the error, I bet you're loading a path that doesn't exist in `SCNScene(named:)`. Put your `let scene = SCNScene(named: filepath)` inside a `do/try`, `if let`, or `try!`, I'd favor `try!` in this case since you can't proceed if the file's not found.

Comment: Tell that to the runtime :)  Seriously, if you're getting an error at `SCNScene(named:)`, then you've made a mistake in the filename, or the file path, or perhaps you've forgotten to include the DAE file in the bundle. You can't load external DAE files on iOS at runtime; DAE files in your project are compressed using `scntool` at compile time.

Comment: It doesn't works, I'm sorry, i'm novice, and I'm french ^^ No error, but just a black screen

Comment: SceneKit's French too! 1: Precisely what line are you on when you hit the error?  2: Verify that the DAE file and your assets folder are in your target by opening the Xcode File Inspector (option-command-1) and making sure the checkbox is checked for your target, for each of the DAE files you're trying to load. 3: You can build for generic iOS device and then inspect the package contents (Target->Reveal in Finder, then right-click Show Package Contents). Make sure the files are where you think they are.

Comment: If you're no longer getting the fatal error, then your camera is likely pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: I added a constraint to my camera so it is not the problem, but I found a easier solution that is exactly what I need, thanks for your help Hal, I appreciate your help !